# Proving result about vector subspaces - I have a conjecture

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over field $K$ and let $V$ have basis $\{v_{-n},...,v_{-1}, v_1,... v_n \}$. Let $e_{i, j}$ be the matrix of the map $v_k \mapsto \delta_{jk} v_i $ where $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta. So here $e_{i,j}$ is just a matrix with a single entry $1$ and the rest $0$. Define $A_{i,j}$ to be the matrix $e_{i,j}-e_{-j, -i}$ .
Let $\mathscr{A} =\{A_{i,j} : i+j<0 \}$.

I'm trying to show that if $U$ is a nonzero subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $A(u) \in U $ for all $A \in \mathscr{A} $ and all $u \in U$. Then $U=V$.

My intuition tells me that there should be a way of showing that at least one of the basis elements $v_i$ is in $U$ and then from there you can show that $U$ must contain all the basis elements and so $U=V$.But I'm having trouble showing my first claim. Anyone have a clue or a better way of showing the result?

Comment: Any such $U$ must in particular be an invariant subspace of each individual $A_{i,j}$; and you can calculate the invariant subspaces of each $A_{i,j}$ by hand and show that each of them contains a basis vector.

Comment: How can you calculate the invariant subspaces here?

Comment: The usual way: Pick a specific $A_{i,j}$. What are its eigenvalues $\lambda$? What is the null space of $A_{i,j}-\lambda I$? of $(A_{i,j}-\lambda I)^2$? ... Try a couple of specific examples, it's illuminating here.